# play - 2.2-Java : QOS : How to log event on start(before) & end(after) of the method using annotations , actions?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I want to generate event on start and end of the method to log time stamp for QOS & instrumentation purpose. In spring framework that it is easy to achieve using AOP without writing boiler plate code in each of the methods.

I want to do similar in play. I looked in action & @with annotation however it is not giving desired result.

What is best way to log event & time stamp on start (before) and on completion (after) method?

Below is my action class:

```
import play.libs.F.Promise;
import play.mvc.Action;
import play.mvc.Http;
import play.mvc.SimpleResult;

public class PublishEventAction extends Action<PublishEvent> {

    @Override
    public Promise<SimpleResult> call(Http.Context context) throws Throwable
    {


        try { 
            before(context); 
            Promise<SimpleResult> result = delegate.call(context); // This part calls your real action method 
            after(context); 
            return result; 
          } catch (RuntimeException e) { 
            throw e; 
          } catch (Throwable t) { 
            throw new RuntimeException(t); 
          } 


    }

    private void before(Http.Context context) { 
        // Do the before things here

        System.out.println("Before: " + context.request().path()+context.toString()+"current time : "+System.currentTimeMillis());
      } 

      private void after(Http.Context context) { 
        // Do the after things here
          System.out.println("After: " + context.request().path()+context.toString()+"current time : "+System.currentTimeMillis());
      } 

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept before and after the request like shown below and log all your requests:

```
public Action onRequest(final Http.Request request, Method method) {

    Action action =  new Action.Simple() {
        public Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
            Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Promise<Result> result = delegate.call(ctx);

            //This part is not executed immediately
            Long finish = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Logger.info("method=" + request.method() + " uri=" + request.uri() + " remote-address=" + request.remoteAddress() + " time=" + (finish-start));

            return result;
        }
    };
    return action;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an [action composition](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/JavaActionsComposition). In the play documentation is explained how to execute any code BEFORE the action is fired. But you can also use for AFTER like described in [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/play-framework/029vvEuPUfQ).

Comment: I was trying to achieve same however as my method returns - Promise<SimpleResult> the - @after immediately gets executed. i want to execute after() once result is available to capture real result processing time and not promise of result. I tried onRedeem however it doesn't have handle on context. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Global class extending GlobalSettings at the root of your "app" package and intercept every request:

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

```
public Action onRequest(Request request, Method actionMethod) {
    Logger.debug("Request starts:" + request.toString());
    Action action = super.onRequest(request, actionMethod);
    Logger.debug("Request ends.");

    return action;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned you want to extend the Global Settings object.

Play's documentation is solid: [Application Global Settings](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaGlobal) and [Intercepting Requests](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaInterceptors)

```
import play.*;
import play.mvc.Action;
import play.mvc.Http.Request;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    public Action onRequest(Request request, Method actionMethod) {
        System.out.println("before each request..." + request.toString());
        return super.onRequest(request, actionMethod);
    }

}
```

The documentation explains that if you want to intercept a specific action, you can do so with [action composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaActionsComposition).